# Catagorizing messages in chronicle queue for reading

Tags: chronicle-queue

I want to use chronicle queue to store messages using the high level API as mentioned in the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274284/chronicle-consumer-not-reading-records-correctly) question. But I also want some kind of key for my messages as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498047/chronicle-vs-chronicle-queue-package)

1.) Firstly , is this the right/efficient way to read/write using high level API? - Code samples below

2.) How do I separate different category of messages? For example "get me all messages for a particular key , the key in code sample below being ric". Maybe use different topics in the same queue? But how would I do that?

Here's my test code to write to the queue:

```
public void saveHighLevel(MyInterface obj)
{
    try (ChronicleQueue queue = ChronicleQueue.singleBuilder(_location).build()) {
        ExcerptAppender appender = queue.acquireAppender();
        MyInterface trade = appender.methodWriter(MyInterface.class);
        // Write
        trade.populate(obj);
    }
}
```

And here's one to read:

```
public void readHighLevel()
{
    try(ChronicleQueue queue = ChronicleQueue.singleBuilder(_location).build()) {
        ExcerptTailer tailer = queue.createTailer();
        MyInterface container = new MyData();
        MethodReader reader = tailer.methodReader(container);
        while (reader.readOne()) {
            System.out.println(container);
        }
    }
}
```

MyInterface:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    public double getPrice();
    public int getSize();
    public String getRic();
    public void populate(MyInterface obj);
}
```

Implementation of populate:

```
 public void populate(MyInterface obj)
 {
    this.price = obj.getPrice();
    this.ric = obj.getRic();
    this.size = obj.getSize();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for part (2) of my question in the question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659453/regarding-sub-topics-in-chronicle-queue) post.

Essentially by doing:
`ChronicleQueue queue = ChronicleQueue.singleBuilder("Topic/SubTopic").build();`

where Topic can be substituted with the key I'm looking for.